# Regarding solving for the coordinates of reflection points in 3D space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, 3d

In space, there exists a smooth plane, and additionally, there are two points, denoted as $A (x_a, y_a, z_a)$ and $B (x_b, y_b, z_b)$. A beam of light is emitted from point A, reflects off the mirror surface of the smooth plane at a reflection point P, and finally arrives at point B. Now, we can obtain the mirror image point of B with respect to the smooth plane, denoted as $B' = (x_b', y_b', z_b')$. How can I calculate the expression for point P in the most elegant and simple way?

Comment: This is an odd set0up unless you are also given an equation for the "smooth plane" in which the reflection occurs. Also it would seem the point P is not determined without knowing the reflection plane.

Comment: But I know the mirror image of one of the points with respect to the plane. Isn't that enough to determine the parameters of the plane?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Consider this figure.DP is perpendicular to plane FG  and B' is the mirror of B about the plane. Fundamental optic theorem says  for reflection we must have:

$\angle APD=\angle BPD$

To find coordinate of P we connect B' to A; P is the intersection of line AB' and plane FG. I show calculations in this example:

Let:

Equation of the plane: $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$

The coordinates of mirror of $B:(x_0, y_0, z_0) is:

$B': (x_0-2A\lambda, y_0-2B\lambda, Z_0-2C\lambda)$

$\lambda=\frac{Ax_0+By_0+Cz_0+D}{A^2+B^2+C^2}$

Example:

Plane:  $2x+y+z+4=0$

$A:(1, -1, 2)$

$B: (0, 1, 1)$

Using the formula you get:

$\lambda=\frac{2\times 0+1\times 1+1\times 1 +4}{2^2+1^2+1^2}=1$

$B': (-4, -1, -1)$

Equation of line AB':

$\frac{x+4}5=\frac{y+1}{-2}=\frac{z+1}3=t\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space(1)$

finding x, y and z in terms of t and putting in the equation of the plane we finally get:

$t=\frac 6{11}$

Putting t in (1) gives:

$P: ( \frac {-32}{11}, \frac {-23}{11}, \frac 7{11})$

Update: If you can obtain the coordinate of B' then you can find the equation of plan as follows:

1): the components of the direction vector of line BB' is :

$(l, m, n)=(x_b-x'_b, y_b-y'_b, z_b-z'_b)$

This is the normal of the plane. The point the plane passes is the mid point of BB'; lets denote it as M:

$(x_M, y_M, z_M)=(\frac{x_b+x'_b}2, \frac{y_b+y'_b}2, \frac{z_b+z'_b}2)$

Hence the equation of the plane will be:

$l(x-x_M)+m(y-y_M)+n(z-z_m)=0$

and the equation of line AB' is:

$\frac{x-x'_b}{x_a-x'_b}=\frac{y-y'_b}{y_a-y'_b}=\frac{z-z'_b}{z_a-z'_b}=t$

P will be the intersection of AB' and the plane. The rule  to find the coordinates of P is as I said in the example.

Comment: Nice, but you take the _"smooth plane"_ as flat. Why not baubles or a car's bonnet with a shiny surface? Or implies **plane** flat and nothing else but flat?

Comment: @m-stgt, The  optic law is valid in all shapes, flat, concave or convex. But in all cases the surface must be shiny.

Comment: So you regard only the tessera holding point $P$, that _many other "tesseras"_ (other location, different angle) will do too is another story :)

Comment: @m-stgt, Yes, don't forgetr we are talking about a single ray of light. Also any surface is comprised of infinite number of tesseras.In concave surface the rays converge to one point which is the focus of the suface and in convex the rays diverge, these effects are because of small angles  between the tesseras.